# OCaml native compiler for HP-UX IA64

Tags: ocaml, hp-ux, itanium

Is there a way to build a stable OCaml native compiler for HP-UX IA64?

I stumbled upon the comment below on https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6711348

> We actively use/used OCaml in production on SPARC/Solaris, POWER/AIX, HP-UX/IA64. (The optimized compiler wouldn't build on AIX.)

I googled about this but couldn't find any useful information. So now I'm trying to

- Build HP-UX IA64 OCaml bytecode interpreter (and ship my code with)
- Mix HP-UX build process with IA64 code generator for other platforms in the official source codes

But no hope until now. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You should really ask that on the mailing list or the bugtracker, where one of the maintainer of the language can answer you.